# make terminal show up when called in a shell script

Tags: command-line

I am writing a shell script that will execute some application for a specific mime type, and it does it correctly, but when I have echo in my shell script, I dont see any terminal with the echoes message, is there any way to make the terminal show ?

Comment: How do you invoke the shell script?

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning for this script to always execute in a windowed environment, and these messages are only used for rare errors, consider using xmessage or gmessage instead of echo. This will bring up a new window with the message, which the user can click to dismiss.

On the other hand, if the messages are common or frequent, you might want to always run your entire script inside a new terminal window for that mime type. Instead of configuring it to run your script, try running this:

```
gnome-terminal -e "path to your script"
```

I assume you also need to pass the name of the file to open to the script, but I'm not sure how that parameter is encoded in the context where you're doing this. It might be as simple as putting something like $* or %s at the right spot inside the quotes.